# Why "the" widow in Y'vamos chapter 9?

Tags: masechet-yevamot

The first couple of *mishnayos* in [chapter nine of *Y'vamos*](//www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Yevamot.9) list classes of women, each of whom is permitted to marry her first husband but forbidden [to marry his brother on his childless death](/tags/yibbum-chalitza-levirate/info), or vice versa, or forbidden to marry either, or permitted to marry both. The lists contain the following classes of woman:

- האלמנה, the widow
- כשרה, (in this context, roughly) someone allowed to marry a *kohen*
- חללה, (roughly) someone not allowed to marry a *kohen*
- בת ישראל, (in this context, roughly) someone who is not a [*mamzeres*](/tags/mamzer/info) or convert
- ממזרת, a *mamzeres*

Why is the first of those definite ("the") and the rest not?

Comment: Battenura girsa is almanac without HA

Comment: perhaps because את ??????

Comment: The problem is general to the Mishnah, they weren't exact in many many cases. Compare שבת הגדול and the likes. The interpretations you expect to hear came much later to "compensate" their inconsistency.

Comment: Tosafot ([Kidushin 2a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.2a.1?lang=he&p2=Tosafot_on_Kiddushin.2a.1.1&lang2=he)) ask the same question on a different mishna. Their first answer (definite article used for cases mentioned in the Torah) seems to me to be almost valid here. The only problem is that I would expect החללה

Comment: May be a good answer @ba